# Can junction box be placed on insulation above ceiling drywall?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling, fire-hazard, fire-safety

I am thinking of installing these lights on my ceiling. Each light comes with its own junction box that you just leave inside the ceiling. My ceiling, however, has insulation right above it. Is it safe to leave a junction box like that right on top of the insulation or jammed between the drywall and the insulation?

[image: Ultra-Thin LED Recessed Ceiling Light with Junction Box]

*Source: Amazon.com - Ensenior LED Recessed Ceiling Light*

Comment: You say your ceiling has insulation "underneath it"  do you mean just above it? If so, please edit your question to make it more accurate.

Comment: Is access to the JB from the attic a possibility?

Comment: No, there is no access to the attic.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the isolation is right above it lying on the drywall.

Comment: I edited the text for you, and cropped the picture. Have a good weekend.

Comment: I found conflicting information, have you tried your local or state building codes? You  might like to look at a few links- https://www.bobvila.com/posts/83087-fiberglass-insulation-around-junction-box https://structuretech.com/qa-can-electrical-boxes-buried-insulation/

Comment: You meet the main requirement you can pop the light to get to the junction box. Ask your local electrical inspector if he would approve you using these.